# API facebook, token, Java, Spring

Tags: java, spring, facebook, facebook-api, token

В каком виде приходит ответ от facebook, после отправки запроса

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&grant_type=client_credentials
```

с помощью

```
ResponseEntity<?> response = restTemplate.exchange(testUrl, HttpMethod.GET, null, ?.class, urlParameters);
```

В каком формате должен быть класс, чтобы конвертер смог преобразовать приходящий ответ в класс?

Comment: сделайте запрос через браузер, вы получите `json`, на его основе сделайте обект

Comment: очень похоже, что вы используете не правильный API. поясните словами, что вы хотите сделать? и где вы взяли информацию о текущем способе?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman все работает верно. Предыдущий вопрос очень помог увидеть, что именно мне присылают.